# how to display suggestion dropdown when user types the second @ in the input field using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am displaying a suggestion dropdown when a user types @ in the input field.

the code below works in the below scenarios,

-> when the user types @ as the starting character displays all users in the suggestion dropdown.

-> entering @user filters dropdown list based on string "user"

-> entering @ anywhere in the string displays the suggestion dropdown.

But I want it to show the suggestion dropdown even when the user types "hello @user" and then retypes "hello @ @user" now I want the dropdown to be shown at first @ char where the cursor is placed currently.

How can I fix the code below to do it?

```
class UserMention extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: "",
            user_list: [
                { name: "John smith" },
                { name: "Jenna surname2" },
                { name: "Tuija rajala" }
            ],
            suggestions: []
        };
    }

   handleOnChange = e => {
      const { value } = e.target;
      const { user_list } = this.state;
     //show all user suggestions
     if (value.includes("@") && value.indexOf("@") === value.length - 1) {
         this.setState({
             text: value,
             suggestions: [...this.state.user_list]
         });
         //show matching user suggesstions
     } else if (value.includes("@") && value.length > 1) {
         const stringAfterAt = value.slice(value.indexOf("@") +          1).toLowerCase();
         const newSuggestions = user_list.filter(user => {
             return user.name.toLowerCase().includes(stringAfterAt);
         });
         this.setState({
             text: value,
             suggestions: newSuggestions
         });
         //display no users if they do not use the @ symbol
    } else {
        this.setState({
            text: value,
            suggestions: []
        });
    }
  };

 createSuggestionsList = () => {
     const { suggestions } = this.state;
     return suggestions.map(user => {
         return <div>{user.name}</div>;
     });
 };

 render = () => {
     return (
         <div>
             <input
                 required
                 name="text"
                 value={this.state.text}
                 onChange={this.handleOnChange}
              />
              {this.createSuggestionsList()}
         </div>
    );
  };
}
```

Could someone help me solve this? Thanks.

Comment: I'd avoid using cursor position for this - could you use `value.startsWith('@')` instead? Edit: scratch that, wouldn't match for the 'hello' part.

Comment: thanks for the reply. so do you mean using value.startsWith in else if statement alone does that?

Answer (score 0):

Well, however you want to drop down anything, it sounds like simply finding whether a string has two @ versus one @ is the thing you're throwing far more code at than needed.

Here's a [jsbin of using regex to solve that problem](https://jsbin.com/zumiwin/edit?js,console).

```
'your @ string @'.match(/@/g).length
```

This is the major operable piece.  It simply compares your string to the regex of "@".  / / makes a regex literal.  The g on the end is for global/greedy, and selects more than one.  Match returns an array, which you can detect the length of.

As for the dropdown itself, you might do something like this in your render method:

```
render(){
    return (
    <div className="dropdownElement" style={{display: this.state.inputString.match(/@/g).length>2?'block':'none' }}>
       {content}
    </div>)
}
```

Do let me know if either of these don't make much sense.  I used a ternary in a JS expression in JSX in the render method, which could be done as a standard if statement.